# Why does VSCode need forever to find references and fail to rename symbols?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, refactoring

I have a Python 3 function named `foo`. When I right click on this function in my VSCode editor and select `Go to Reference` it takes over a minute for the reference window to pop up. The `Rename Symbol` option does not work at all. If I search for `foo` in the search sidebar opened by `Ctrl + Shift + F` and search for `foo` I get a result instantly (without setting any file filters beforehand. The same applies when searching for references of other functions/variables. The problem is specific to only one of my repositories, although it does not contain significant more lines than the others. Does anybody have a guess how to fix this?

VSCode version: July 2021 (version 1.59)

Answer (score 1):

Simple text based search is expected to be quick. However, all other operations require the language server behind the scene to parse all your source files and understand the entire code model.

If you can reliably reproduce the problem, open an issue on GitHub,

https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues